# Jquery hover a parent div effecting 2 of its grandchild and 1 of its child

Tags: jquery, css

So guys, I want to convert this css hovering code to jquery code.

This is the hovering css version :

index.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row why-us-box">
        <div class="why-item col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
          <div class="why-box-head">
            <i class="fa fa-group"></i>
            <h4>
              <b>Reason 1</b>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <p class="text-center">
            Detail Reason 1
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="why-item col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
          <div class="why-box-head">
            <i class="fa fa-trophy"></i>
            <h4>
              <b>Reason 2</b>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <p class="text-center">
            Detail Reason 2
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="why-item col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
          <div class="why-box-head">
            <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>
            <h4>
              <b>Reason 3</b>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <p class="text-center">
            Detail Reason 3
          </p>
        </div>
      </div><!-- End of why-us-box -->
    </div> <!-- End of container-fluid -->
```

style.css

```
.why-item:hover .why-box-head i {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.4);
    transform:scale(1.4);
}

.why-item:hover .why-box-head h4 {
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
  transform:scale(1.1);
}

.why-item:hover p {
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
  transform:scale(1.1);
}

.why-box-head i {
  color: #607D8B;
  font-size: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.why-box-head h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.why-item p {
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #797979;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
```

And it's work really well, but then I want to try the jquery way.

So, how do you effect the 2 grandchild and a child when the parent div (why-item div) get hovered ?
I want to the effect on :
tag i which is child of why-box-head which is child of why-item (the grandchild)

tag h3 which is child of why-box-head which is child of why-item (the grandchild)

tag p which is child of why-item (the child)

I tried this jquery just to try effecting tag i but it still really confusing to me, let alone effecting 3 tags at the same time.

```
$(".why-item").hover(function(){
    $("why-box-head i").css({"-webkit-transform":"scale(1.4)","transform":"scale(1.4)"});
    }, function(){
    $("why-box-head i").css({"-webkit-transition":"all 0.7s ease","transition":"all 0.7s ease"});
});
```

Comment: Sorry, why do the jquery way?  CSS will be less intensive.  If you need to "do something on hover" just add it with jquery.  Don't stress about using jquery to animate for you.  The only thing you should do with jquery is change classes so the CSS can animate for you

Comment: It's a school homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).find('.why-box-head h4')` to find the relative grandchild in the currently hovered element. And you can add the `p` to the selector, too.

```js
$(".why-item").hover(
  function() {
    $(this)
      .find(".why-box-head h4, p")
      .css({ "-webkit-transform": "scale(1.1)", transform: "scale(1.1)" })
      .end()
      .find('.why-box-head i')
      .css({'-webkit-transform':'scale(1.4)',
    'transform':'scale(1.4)'});
  },
  function() {
    $(this)
      .find(".why-box-head h4, p")
      .css({ "-webkit-transform": "scale(1)", transform: "scale(1)" })
      .end()
      .find('.why-box-head i')
      .css({'-webkit-transform':'scale(1)',
    'transform':'scale(1)'});
  }
);
```

```css
.why-box-head i {
  color: #607D8B;
  font-size: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.why-box-head h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.why-item p {
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #797979;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row why-us-box">
    <div class="why-item col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
      <div class="why-box-head">
        <i class="fa fa-group"></i>
        <h4>
              <b>Reason 1</b>
            </h4>
      </div>
      <p class="text-center">
        Detail Reason 1
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="why-item col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
      <div class="why-box-head">
        <i class="fa fa-trophy"></i>
        <h4>
              <b>Reason 2</b>
            </h4>
      </div>
      <p class="text-center">
        Detail Reason 2
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="why-item col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
      <div class="why-box-head">
        <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>
        <h4>
              <b>Reason 3</b>
            </h4>
      </div>
      <p class="text-center">
        Detail Reason 3
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of why-us-box -->
</div>
<!-- End of container-fluid -->
```

Comment: Your jquery script only affecting the tag i, what if I want to affecting 2 other tags when hovering the parent div? Should I write another hover function or maybe there is another way ?

Comment: `.find(".why-box-head h4, p")` that targets the h4 and p. you can put multiple elements in there depending on what you want to target.

Comment: what about the tag i , which is the grand child? Would it be like this => .find(".why-box-head h4, .why-box-head i, p") ???

Comment: @phaphapha yes.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it doesnt work, when I hover the parent div, there is no change at all.

Comment: This one works. Actually, the earlier is also working fine, It's just silly me for putting <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> AND <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/custom.js"></script> on the head tag instead of the bottom near closed body tag.